# php loop session variable

Tags: php, session

Trying to run a loop based on a session variable.
On the first page load no session.
when it sets the session i sets a session variable and alerts.

Problem being, it alerts every page load :(

```
`
<!-- language: lang-php -->

$check = $_SESSION['cache'];  

if ($check == "xYx") {  

echo $word;  
} else {  

session_start();  
?><script>alert ("Im reading it again !")</script><?  

echo $word;  
$_SESSION['cache'] = "xYx";  
}
```

`

Comment: You have to start the session before you can read from it.

Comment: thats kind of the point, so since on first read $check would not equal xYx, it would then create the session and set $check to xYx.

Comment: Like Alex said, you have to call session_start() before using the $_SESSION superglobal. "The read callback will retrieve any existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will be unserialized and used to automatically populate the $_SESSION superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back to PHP session handling." http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Then on the second pass $check should be equal to xYx so it doesnt alert or call the start the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
session_start();
$check = $_SESSION['cache'];  

if ($check == "xYx") {  

echo $word;  
} else {  

?><script>alert ("Im reading it again !")</script><?  

echo $word;  
$_SESSION['cache'] = "xYx";  
}
```

Which is just simply moving `session_start()` to the beginning as the comments said.

Comment: perfect, i knew it would be simples.
Thx for the speedy replies.

Answer (score 1):

```
$check = $_SESSION['cache'];
```

happens before

```
session_start();
```

which doesn't work.